# Passed Review Audit — no Next button

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

I just passed a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3596452) (for close votes) but the rectangle did not include a button to allow me to continue.

For example…

[image]

Comment: It's like you got the correct answer after the "Halt! None shall pass!" and then he didn't let you pass anyways...

Comment: I was going to suggest that maybe it was the last "review", but then I noticed it was the CV queue...

Comment: @GenericHolidayName - nope it was the SO Close Review queue so I think there might be a few more reviews to do - unless a counter has rolled over to 0 :)

Comment: I notice this to. A workaround is to just click the review tab link on the right (which gives you the next one).

Comment: The counter did roll over to 0. Because [you made 20 reviews today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/151019/mark?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil - I have done a few reviews since then and count today is only 24 now so less than 20 when I got the review

Comment: Hmm, sorry, don't know the limit for these reviews, bad judgement.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil The limit is 40 in the Close Votes queue.

Comment: You reached the end of the Close Vote queue... We wish.

Comment: I think the relevant html/js should be reviewed for the weird behavior then?

Comment: I got this also on the first posts queue after an audit.

Comment: I just got this issue for the late answer queue: http://imagebin.org/282657

Comment: The browser back button is also misbehaving: it always shows the last reviewed post faded out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rendering of the `Next` and `I Understand` buttons was broken, as already reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211953/missing-content-in-completed-review-items).

The fix is already on it's way. Watch out for build rev `2013.12.16.1774` on meta and `2013.12.16.12.1240` on sites.