# Missing content in completed review items

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

The content of completed review items is missing. Here's a screenshot from the reopen review queue on Stack Overflow, but I'm seeing this everywhere: SO, graduated and beta sites, in all queues, and whether or not I have 10k privileges.

[image: screenshot]

I do, however, see my own suggested edits normally. Furthermore, I do see suggested edits normally when not logged in.

Reproduced in Chrome 31.0.1650.57 (where I do have a few userscripts) and in Firefox 25.0 with Greasemonkey turned off. In Chrome, I see this in the Javascript console:

```
⚠ event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:3
⊗ ▼ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendTo' of undefined review.en.js?v=038b38e68e1a:47
     (anonymous function) review.en.js?v=038b38e68e1a:47
     e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
     k review.en.js?v=038b38e68e1a:46
     n jquery.min.js:2
     o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
     w jquery.min.js:4
     d jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: Repo'ed on IE9, First Posts.

Comment: That's not a red _freehand_ circle.

Comment: @MichaelHampton http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97243/bounty-ends-are-too-in#comment244744_97243

Comment: looking, fixing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2013.12.16.1774` for meta and `2013.12.16.12.1240` on sites.

Comment: Localization hit again? By the way the hat fits perfectly, maybe as a dev they'll allow you to keep it for good? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can only tell you that it wasn't caching this time ;)